# Center View in superview

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to center my subview with a button in its superview. So I want the center of the subview be the center of the superview. I'm trying that with following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    var menuView = UIView()
    var newPlayButton = UIButton()
    //var newPlayImage = UIImage(named: "new_game_button_5cs")
    var newPlayImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "new_game_button_5cs"))
    newPlayButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, newPlayImageView.frame.width, newPlayImageView.frame.height)
    newPlayButton.setImage(newPlayImage, forState: .Normal)
    newPlayButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    menuView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    menuView.addSubview(newPlayButton)

    menuView.addConstraint(
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view,
            attribute: .CenterX,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: menuView,
            attribute: .CenterX,
            multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    )
}
```

Unfortunately the program breaks when I try to run it.
(Thread 1: signal SIGABRT)

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint to see where it crashes: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code triggers an assertion saying:

> When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of
>   that view (or the view itself).

This means you have to add `menuView` as a subview to `self.view` before adding constraints. You should also add the constraints to `self.view`, not the `menuView`. Last but not least, remove autoresizing masks constraints that were implicitly added to `menuView` by calling `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` or autolayout will complain about conflicting constraints.

```
menuView.addSubview(newPlayButton)
menuView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

self.view.addSubview(menuView)
self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view,
        attribute: .CenterX,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: menuView,
        attribute: .CenterX,
        multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
)
```